Does time exist if everything is in the present?
In the philosophical concept of presentism, it is posited that only the present exists. The past and future do not exist. This leads me to the thought : if everything is in the present, then does time, as the fourth dimension, cease to exist ?
Does presentism say that time does not exist?

"I don't know man, I just got here myself!"

+1 Great question! Precisely stated and my answer is yes, according to presentism I don't think time exists or at least its continuity exists.

Yes, just not in its usual interpretation. If there was no time the existing present would always be the same, but it changes.

"Time is Nature's way of keeping everything from happening at once."

Do the faraway stars exist in the present or the past? When we see a supernova, is it currently happening or did it happen already? Why?

As with lots of things in physics,  existence doesn't matter.  So long as we have this model idea called "time" and it turns out to be fantastically useful in predicting how things work,  that's all that matters.    yes,  IAAP

It depends on what you mean by exists, & what you mean by time.

There's a slight misconception here. Presentism is the theory that only present things exist.
This means that things in the past do not exist and things in the future do not exist. So, there is no real sense in which we can say that Winston Churchill exists and no real sense in which we can say that the 100th President exists.
This is more about what entities we are ontologically committed to than the existence of time itself.

The criticism from some physics opinions is that there is no common present; that elsewhere it may be the future or the past. Relativity make absolute simultaneity unobservable, so it is only treated as possible. But it's not incalculable, as with GPS synchronisation. A common present means present things exist. If it's not a common present that makes time a pretzel.

I understand, though I guess the critique is more something like: "If only present things exist and what is present is a matter of perspective, then what things exist is a matter of perspective. This is unacceptable." This doesn't really say anything about the existence of time per se. Time could still exist, there could still be a common present, it's just that this common present instantiates different objects for different people.

I think the issue is more physical than phenomenological.  If NASA can coordinate the simultaneity of events on the Earth and the moon i.e. Coordinated Lunar Time by time-dilation correction that is satisfactorily and objectively marking the present. Time may be flowing differently on the moon compared to Earth but the coordinated events are still simultaneous, and at the moment of happening they are in the common present.

@ChrisDegnen: The simultaneity is frame-dependent. We don't have to go to outer space; we have situations on Earth where communication between computers may be simultaneous or not depending on frame. Regarding LTC, the 2024 White House memo acknowledges in (1)(b) (p2) that relativity "holds important implications"; "due to relativistic effects, events that appear simultaneous at the Earth … are not simultaneous to an observer at the Moon."

If you want to make the claim that time does not exist then you will have to justify it by providing an alternative theory to General Relativity to explain the existence of gravity. According to GR, if you step off a cliff, you experience what seems to be the force of gravity attracting you to the Earth because you are coasting along a geodesic in spacetime which is curved in such a way that as your time coordinate increases, your spatial coordinates change in the direction of the Earth's surface.
One way to reconcile presentism with GR is to relax the claim that future and past times do not exist, but recognise that although they exist they are empty, since all of matter exists in the current present. You exist in a given region of spacetime now, and have immediately vacated it by passing on into later regions. You might find some claims to the effects that presentism, of the sort I have outlined, is incompatible with Special Relativity, but those claims are based on a naive interpretation of the meaning of simultaneity, so you can safely ignore them.

It's the "many moments" interpretation of physics!

Can you articulate what role would an optical atomic clock play in your description? https://www.npl.co.uk/insights/measuring-gravitation-with-optical-atomic-clocks An observer walks to the edge of a tall cliff, the clock moving with the observer ticks at some resonant frequency, and when the observer goes into freefall with the clock, does the observer recognize a change in the clock frequency? In my view there is resonant frequency as the inverse of time because we exist with memory and we count the elapsed cycles of the clock to invent the concept of linear time. Reality is not spacetime.

@SystemTheory: The observer who falls off the cliff should see no change in the clock's apparent rate. A (different) stationary observer should see the clock slowing down ever so slightly (it would be difficult to tell without using a second atomic clock, and comparing them with very high precision).

Galileo compared the periodic motion of a pendulum, or the diminishing level of water in a chamber, to the motion of some other object, such as a rolling ball on an incline plane or horizontal surface. Technically motion is the change in position of an object in space. This change of position is called displacement. The displacement of the clock is compared with the displacement of some other object. Galileo puts the object displacement in the numerator and the clock displacement in the denominator to define speed. He defines accleration as the change of speed.
By counting the periodic displacement changes in the clock we have a means to specify the elapsed time or change in time on a discrete or continuous basis. Time is the inverse of frequency of a resonant or rotating system. The resonant displacement has cycles or oscillations that map to the trigonometric functions on the unit circle. The resonance property of nature, the capacity to compare displacement, the ability to make ratios, and human memories give us the concept of elapsed time.
I would argue that resonance is a property of eternal nature and time is a human invention. We age and die. Many, but not all, natural events seem to be irreversible from our perspective. We imagine the arrow of time from birth to death or from the Big Bang to some ultimate state. We also imagine the Bang Bang Bang theory of an expanding and collapsing universe or the invisible multiverse, etc. But eternal nature exists independent of our human perceptions of time! The observer and the observed both have a property of eternity which transcends the perception of time!

@Marco Ocram, indeed targeted a fundamental part of the topic, but relativity is in fact considered as deficient (by presentism) in describing reality and so openly challenged. Besides that, it's not that presentism considers time not to exist, but that things do not exist except in the present. This view (presentism/A-theory) seems more compatible with a teleological understanding of reality in which the ontology of things is enclosed in their potentiality (in it's Aristotelian meaning), rather than existing independently in a 4d space time. So, the general idea is that the evolution of something, ex. a seed becoming a tree, is the expression of the potentiality that is actualized in the present; that potentiality always exist within the seed, in every present...

How is relativity deficient?

@Corbin,  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presentism/#RelaPhys

@Corbin, ...  "According to presentism, therefore, special relativity is radically deficient as a description of reality." ...

Note how the SEP article has to fight against scientific evidence, step by step, and doesn't get anywhere. Also note that GPS exists. So, is relativity deficient, or are presentists deluded?

@Corbin, I am just stating the situation here.

You're repeating what SEP says without considering that SEP's authors might be wrong. Arguments from authority should always be inspected. Why should we consider the presentist claim that relativity is deficient? "One person's modus ponens is another's modus tollens," and I'm not sure why we should give any more credence to presentism.

@Corbin, https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation?paperid=112501

To be fair, this is not precisely true. Not all presentists think that relativity is deficient. There are theories such as the cone-theory that try to reconcile the two positions while still maintaining support for the scientific evidence.

Gift 2021 doesn't show issues with relativity. It is walking through Lorentz transformations without explaining why these equations should work. Gift repeatedly acknowledges that the experimental data supports relativity: clocks dilate and compress relative to each other, photons experience Doppler effects without changing speed, etc. It's also worth noting that Gift is a relativity skeptic who has published several attempts to experimentally disprove relativity, none of which are accepted by cosmologists.

From a mathematical point of view we would consider as follows. Let us suppose that we live in two dimensional world of Flatland. Our motion and our perception would be limited to planar frame. This does not mean that a third dimension (say height) would not exist. In fact a being of three dimensional world would perceive it (think approximately human and ant). This would mean that we -as "Flatlanders"- would be at a constant height (a constant point of the third dimension), hence the third dimension would not vary for us. The non variation of the third dimension for us is the reason of non perception or the "absence" for us but not for its inexistence. If presentism supposes that there is absolutely only presence, then yes, it is necessary to accept the absence of time.
However I cannot get away from mentioning that there is a statement about God's view: God can see the world as a whole, in an extratemporal way, with past, present and future coexisting. This is an example of relative presentism, for we, human beings, seem that we are immersed in temporality.
